# PL SQL birthday between two dates based on persons date of birth

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to see if a person birthday falls within two dates based on their date of birth regardless of year of birth.

So far i am trying the 'ddd' option by getting the day of the year. But what i noticed with my code is that it seems to omit anyone who is born on the 31st of December of a year and therefore getting an incorrect result.I have tried adding a 1 but that doesn't help either. Here is what I have tried so far:-

```
select emp.employee_number, 
       person.title, 
       person.surname, 
       person.first_forname, 
       addr.line_one ||' '|| addr.line_two ||' '|| addr.line_three ||' '|| addr.line_four ||' '||         
       addr.postcode as Address,
       post.long_desc as LONG_DESC, 
       email.email_address,
       per.pers_mobile_tel_no as mobile_no    
from person per 
inner join emp emp on per.person_ref=emp.person_ref
inner join addr addr on per.address_ref= addr.ref
inner join ph ph on emp.person_ref=ph.person_ref
inner join post post on ph.ref=post.ref
inner join pl pl on pl.post_ref= post.ref 
where
 to_char( (  TO_DATE(person.birth_date,'DD-MM-YYYY')) , 'ddd' ) >=  
      to_char( (  TO_DATE(:Start_Date,'DD-MON-YYYY')) , 'ddd' )   
AND 
 to_char( (  TO_DATE(person.birth_date,'DD-MM-YYYY')) , 'ddd' ) <=  
      to_char( (  TO_DATE(:End_Date,'DD-MON-YYYY')) , 'ddd' ) 
and
  ph.end_date is null
and loc.location_number in ('501')
order by emp.employee_number
```

Any help on this will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is person.birth_date defined as a VARCHAR2 column in the table? Or as DATE?

Answer (score 2):

Your query works wrong for the 31th of December because of these conditions:

```
to_char( (  TO_DATE(person.birth_date,'DD-MM-YYYY')) , 'ddd' ) >=  
      to_char( (  TO_DATE(:Start_Date,'DD-MON-YYYY')) , 'ddd' )   
AND 
 to_char( (  TO_DATE(person.birth_date,'DD-MM-YYYY')) , 'ddd' ) <=  
      to_char( (  TO_DATE(:End_Date,'DD-MON-YYYY')) , 'ddd' )
```

You use less or equal and more or equal in both cases. It should be

```
to_char( (  TO_DATE(person.birth_date,'DD-MM-YYYY')) , 'ddd' ) > 
      to_char( (  TO_DATE(:Start_Date,'DD-MON-YYYY')) , 'ddd' )   
AND 
 to_char( (  TO_DATE(person.birth_date,'DD-MM-YYYY')) , 'ddd' ) <=  
      to_char( (  TO_DATE(:End_Date,'DD-MON-YYYY')) , 'ddd' )
```

or

```
to_char( (  TO_DATE(person.birth_date,'DD-MM-YYYY')) , 'ddd' ) >=
      to_char( (  TO_DATE(:Start_Date,'DD-MON-YYYY')) , 'ddd' )   
AND 
 to_char( (  TO_DATE(person.birth_date,'DD-MM-YYYY')) , 'ddd' ) <  
      to_char( (  TO_DATE(:End_Date,'DD-MON-YYYY')) , 'ddd' )
```

EDIT:
 The query seems not to solve your problem. For example, let's say the birth day is 31.12.1990, start date is 01.06.1990 and end date is 01.02.1991. When you get the 'ddd', you have 365 for birth day, 152 for start date and 32 for end date. However, 32 is less than 152, so you will not get the person with 31.12.1990 in your output. So, comparing with 'ddd' value is incorrect as it ignores the year value. Instead, you should compare the whole dates with each other as:

```
TO_DATE(person.birth_date,'DD-MM-YYYY') >=
          TO_DATE(:Start_Date,'DD-MON-YYYY') 
AND 
TO_DATE(person.birth_date,'DD-MM-YYYY') <  
          TO_DATE(:End_Date,'DD-MON-YYYY')
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your help. I have tried the above but I still cannot seem to capture the 31st of December. I am trying with input dates 1st January 2014 to 31st December 2014. But for some reason that one person born on the 31st of December is not showing up.

Comment: Can you, please, provide your input data?

Comment: Thanks here is my data. The data is all string based the dates are not held in datetime fields.

001211 MR  ROBERT 3 Bendicks Avneue House Plumber  07892312312 Plumb Section 04-JUN-64
001212 MR  Geere 5 Havlock Way  Plater   07887654345 Plates  31-DEC-97 

I have tried using TO_NUMBER as well but still no result.

Comment: As I understand '31-DEC-97' is the birth date and '04-JUN-64' is the start date. What is the end date?

Comment: Both are birth dates. The scenario is if someone wants to check if  someones birthday falls with two dates given (the inputs startdate and enddate). It seems to work for nearly all scenarios but I ran a test using dates 1st January 2014 to 31st December thus trying to grab everyones birthday but have noticed that anyone who has a birthday on the 31st December doesn't get included. But if I hard code a number in and add 366 as day number using the to_number function then it works but as it is it excludes any person with a birthdate of 31st Decemver.

Comment: I think I got your problem. For example, let's say the birth day is 31.12.1990, start date is 01.06.1990 and end date is 01.02.1991. When you get the 'ddd', you have 365 for birth day, 152 for start date and 32 for end date. However, 32 is less than 152, so you will not get the person with 31.12.1990 in your output. I will add it to my answer.

Comment: Not quite but your nearly there. A persons date of birth is not important but the day and month is. the search will always be between two dates in the same year. So say I am looking for people whose birthday is coming up between the 1st of December and the 31st of December. I seem to get everybody except for the people born on the 31st December. The 31st of December equates to 365 and hence I am using <= to in order that it captures those on the 31st Dec. But for some strange reason it does not. Weird. Thanks for your input. I just want to make sure I am not going mad.

Comment: I have tried this as well but still no joy:-

to_number(to_char( (  TO_DATE(per.birth_date,'DD-MM-YYYY')) , 'ddd' ),'999') >=  to_number(to_char( (  TO_DATE(:Start_Date,'DD-MON-YYYY')) , 'ddd' ),'999')   AND 
to_number(to_char( (  TO_DATE(per.birth_date,'DD-MM-YYYY')) , 'ddd' ),'999') <  to_number(to_char( (  TO_DATE(:End_Date,'DD-MON-YYYY')) , 'ddd' ),'999')